# Angular material date picker: Date Parsing UTC problem 1 day before

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material, utc

I know there are several threads about this and i read them all but couldn't fix this for days. I might found a solution but it seems to be do dirty for me.

So as other users I have the same problem with the datePicker. For me it's the Angular Material Datepicker `mat-datepicker`

When I log the value I get the correct result:

```
Wed Dec 24 1999 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)
```

but in the request it is

```
1999-12-23T23:00:00.000Z
```

What I tried yet:

I've added `{ provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: { useUtc: true } }` to my `component` and to my `app.module.ts`. That does not make any difference for me.

My dirty solution (before sending the request):

```js
 let newDate= new Date(this.personalForm.get("dateOfBirth").value);
 newDate.setMinutes(newDate.getMinutes() - newDate.getTimezoneOffset());
```

When I am doing this the console logs:

```
Wed Dec 24 1999 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)
```

and the request is right:

```
1997-12-24T00:00:00.000Z
```

But if somebody now would be from a different timezone like GMT-0100 this would again not work. How to fix this correctly?

I also change the adapter dynamically if it's necessary to know:

```js
 this._adapter.setLocale(this.translateService.currentLang);
```

Comment: in your console.log... convert to UTC string... https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toutcstring.asp

Comment: @AkberIqbal okay I see how it looks in UTC now but how this does help me with my problem? It's still wrong when I don't fix it manually "dirty"

Comment: you need to import `MatMomentDateModule` instead of `MatNativeDateModule` to work `{ provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: { useUtc: true } }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value which is picked and displayed is the same... it is the different formats of the date-time which show us a different result (where the date also changes)!!

**For e.g**:

> - (by default): 2019-06-11T19:00:00.000Z
> - is equal to (by UTCString): Tue, 11 Jun 2019 19:00:00 GMT
> - is equal to (by LocaleString): 6/12/2019, 12:00:00 AM
> - is equal to (by LocaleTimeString): 12:00:00 AM

We don't need to convert it, because the date object contains the same exact time.

[This stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-on63zt) will further show the difference a format can make on the surface but the date is the same underneath; If you have questions/comments, you can fork this stackblitz, make changes and post a comment against this answer, i'll try to clarify.

relevant **TS**:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/** @title Basic datepicker */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-overview-example.css'],
})
export class DatepickerOverviewExample {
  planModel: any = {start_time: new Date() };
  constructor(){}

  dateChanged(evt){
    let selectedDate = new Date(evt);
    console.log("by default:", selectedDate);
    console.log("by UTCString:", selectedDate.toUTCString());
    console.log("by LocaleString:", selectedDate.toLocaleString());
    console.log("by LocaleTimeString:", selectedDate.toLocaleTimeString());
  }

}
```

relevant **HTML**:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date"
  [(ngModel)]="planModel.start_time"
  (ngModelChange)='dateChanged($event)'
  >
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

<hr/>

<p>By default: {{planModel.start_time}} </p>
<p>Medium date: {{planModel.start_time | date:'medium'}} </p>
<p>Short date: {{planModel.start_time | date:'short'}} </p>
<p>Short time: {{planModel.start_time | date: 'shortTime' }} </p>
<p>Medium time: {{planModel.start_time | date: 'mediumTime' }} </p>
<p>Long time: {{planModel.start_time | date: 'longTime' }} </p>
<p>Full time: {{planModel.start_time | date: 'fullTime' }} </p>
```

Comment: It's not the same if I want to display it again in Angular. It's saved in my database with JPA as parsed date that will only be 1999-12-23 without timestamp or just 00:00 and so it's wrong when I want to display it.

Comment: before saving in the database, if do: `let someVar = new Date(parsedDate)`... and then, insert this `someVar` in your database; you can fork my stackblitz to show me what you're experiencing... I or someone else in the community can then help easily

Comment: Sorry I can't follow you. What is `parsedDate`? I mean how and what should I parse? I just want to save the dateOfBirth like I said in the question literally and be able to display it right again in the profile of the user. Maybe my problem is more in my Java backend parsing. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-date-moment-utc?file=app%2Fmoment-utc-adapter.ts if you enter my date here you see what exactly what I get as JSON output for my backend. I format that to be able to save it to my database with a `DateTimeFormatter` and `LocalDate.parse` maybe I also need to use `LocalDateTime`

Comment: even in your stackblitz, the Date object has the same date... the format on the surface can change... check this forked version: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-date-moment-utc-k7wzth?file=app%2Fdatepicker-formats-example.html

Comment: I think we actually talking about different things. I don't know what you want to tell me. I know that the date is always the same just with different timezones. In the end is this 1999-12-23T23:00:00.000Z what I get as request. When I'm saving this in my database and later retrieve it and display it (like I do) as longDate there stands 1999-12-23 what is wrong. I also found it that my lastUpdated date+time is wrong. I edited something minutes ago and it says: 13. June 2019 11:48:58 but it was 13:48:58

Comment: is it possible to get it in milis?

Answer (score 3):

In response to [your own incorrect Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56583534/642706)…

## 11 PM UTC = 00:00+01:00 the next day (same moment)

> Wed Dec 24 1999 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)
>   but in the request it is
>
> 1999-12-23T23:00:00.000Z

These two strings represent the same value. They are two ways of viewing the same moment. One is 11 PM at UTC, the other is an hour ahead of UTC, so it represents the first moment of the next day. Adding one hour to 11 PM on the 23rd in a 24-hour long day takes past the stroke of midnight, to the first moment of the 24th.

## Parsing

Parse your input string as an `Instant`. The Z on the end means UTC and is pronounced “Zulu”. An `Instant` represent a moment in UTC, always UTC, by definition.

Your input string is in standard ISO 8601 format. The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "1999-12-23T23:00:00.000Z" ) ;
```

A moment (a date, a time-of-day, and an assigned time zone or offset-from-UTC) must be saved into a database column of a type akin to the standard-SQL type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. A column of a type akin to `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` would be the *wrong* data type.

To write to your database, we need to switch from the basic building-block class of `Instant` to the more flexible `OffsetDateTime` class. Support for the `OffsetDateTime` class in JDBC drivers is required by JDBC 4.2 and later, while `Instant` support is optional.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Write to database via a `PreparedStatement` with a placeholder `?`.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

This has been discussed many many times on Stack Overflow. So search to learn more. And please search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

## `LocalDate`

If your goal is to track just a date, and you don’t really care about time-of-day and time zone, you should be using `LocalDate` in Java and `DATE` column in standard SQL.

Comment: With my structure it's not even possible to it like this. I just use my repo to save the given entity with all of my values. And this is just a date. In the end it works for me and do not see anything wrong and I will use it again if I don't work with preparedStatements which is not really needed with JPA and Spring

Comment: So is this a better attempt or a right one: `this.dateOfBirth = new Timestamp(ZonedDateTime.of(dob, ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant().toEpochMilli());`

Answer (score 0):

At the end the problem was in my backend and needed to understand what is going on.

To save the Date right into my Postgres Database:

```java
     DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH);
     LocalDateTime lu = LocalDateTime.parse(lastUpdated, inputFormatter);
     LocalDateTime dob = LocalDateTime.parse(dateOfBirth, inputFormatter);

     this.dateOfBirth = Date.from(dob.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant());
     this.lastUpdated = Date.from(lu.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant());
```

Before I had

```java
 this.dateOfBirth = Date.from(dob.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

which was wrong. I just receive the request like it's given by Angular and Java saves it right into the database.

```
1999-12-23T23:00:00.000Z
```

turns into

```
1997-12-24 00:00:00
```

Comment: **Incorrect.** Your formatting pattern ignores the `Z` on the end, which means UTC and is pronounced “Zulu”. So you are needlessly discarding valuable information. And your input should be parsed as a `Instant` not a `LocalDateTime`. The `LocalDateTime` class **cannot represent a moment** as explained in its Javadoc. See corrected code example in [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56588823/642706).